# Angular upgrade own library from 12 to 13 scss Error 'SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.'

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, angular-material, angular13

I'm trying to upgrade my Angular projects from **12** to **13** and running into an issue that I cannot fix since two days of work.

My applications are default Angular Material apps with some functionality like a grocery list app.

To insert items I use a formula with some fields which can be submitted. (MatDialog)
I have outsourced this formula into my own angular library to be a little bit more generic and reusable.

Now, after upgrading the library project and trying to link the resulting build (from new Ivy) into my app I'm getting the error:

```
SassError: Can't find stylesheet to import.

@import '@my/form-lib/theme';
```

The stylesheet which is meant to be unknown comes from the library and provides the default theming access to this library but I cannot determine why this should happen.
I also recognized, that the use of `Angular Material` now doesn't need the tilde ~ anymore.

```
@use '**~**@angular/material' as mat;
```

I have tried to remove all tilde ~ but the error still exists.

I also have tried to reset `@angluar/cli` to *13.0.0* which is described as a solution [here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/23896).
But this doesn't work for me.

Does anyone know a solution to try out?

Comment: You mention `@use` but you use `@import`? Try changing to `@use`

Comment: Should I use @use where I import the theme of my component lib?

Comment: @MathewBerg I tried that, but the same error occured
`@use '@my/form-lib/theme as form-lib; '`

Comment: `@use '@my/form-lib/theme` maybe?

Comment: Where does `@my/form-lib/theme` come from, is it in your project? What happens if you include the path to `@my` in `angular.json` -> `stylePreprocessorOptions.includePaths`?

Comment: Both ideas didn't work .. may be a configuration error in the app project where I linked the library? Because the library's demo project is working fine

Comment: I have the same issue, the demo site in the lib I'm using works perfectly. Also my project works fine, if I don't use `ng serve`. If I build and then serve it externally, it's fine.

Answer (score 10):

the only thing that fixed it for me it's been changing from

```css
@import '@my/lib/scss-file';
```

to

```css
@import 'node_modules/@my/lib/scss-file';
```

Comment: Same worked for me, but why did it work this way?

Comment: I think it's related to the setting `publicPath: "auto"` in the `webpack.config.js`, but I'm not 100% sure about it

Comment: Why this answer doesn't get more visibility?? I lost 1 hour...each time I don't use Angular for a while I forget that I need to do paths like so...